# What properties do similar matrices share?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering if *special* matrices are always similar only to other *special* matrices.

That is:
$\cdot$ Are all of the matrices similar to a symmetric matrix symmetric?
$\cdot$ Are all of the matrices similar to a skew-symmetric matrix skew-symmetric?
$\cdot$ Are all of the matrices similar to a normal matrix normal?
$\cdot$ Are all of the matrices similar to a self-adjoint matrix self-adjoint?
$\cdot$ Are all of the matrices similar to a Hermitian matrix Hermitian?
etc.

Let's try one:
A matrix $A$ is symmetric if $A=A^T$.  Then if $A=P^{-1}BP$, we have $A^T=P^TB^T(P^T)^{-1}$.  Therefore $A^T=A=P^TB^T(P^T)^{-1}=P^{-1}BP$.  Therefore $B=PP^TB^T(P^T)^{-1}P^{-1}$.  Because $P$ is not orthogonal in general, $B \ne B^T$?

NOTE: I could try this for all of them, but I'm pretty sure I'd reach a very similar conclusion in each of the above mentioned cases.

Assuming that this is the correct conclusion here, does this mean that in general the ***specialness* (symmetry, Hermitianness, orthogonality, etc) of matrices is not preserved by a change of basis**?  If not, then there's no way to discuss a symmetric (or otherwise *special*) **transformation** without first defining our basis?

Just curious.

Comment: These properties are not preserved by a change to an arbitrary _linear_ basis (i.e., a linearly independent spanning set), but they are preserved when changing to an _orthonormal_ basis (however, the first two require that the basis be in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: @J.Loreaux  OK. That makes sense.  Because I've heard of "Hermitian transformations" or "unitary transformations" or "skew-symmetric" tranformations without respect to a defined basis, but it didn't make sense if one could just change the basis and get a non-Hermitian/unitary/skew-symmetric/etc tranformation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All of these properties fail to hold for similar matrices in general.  However, they are true if we specify **unitary** similarity; that is, we only allow similarities such that $P^{-1} = P^*$ (or $P^{T}$, if $P$ is real).

---

**Counterexamples:**

$
\pmatrix{1\\&2}
$
is normal, symmetric, self-adjoint, and Hermitian.  But the similar matrix
$
\pmatrix{1&1\\0&2}
$
has none of those properties.

The matrix
$
\pmatrix{0&-2\\2&0}
$
is skew-symmetric, but the similar matrix
$
\pmatrix{0&-1\\4&0}
$
is not.

Comment: Ben is unitary the ONLY case in which symmetry is preserved?

Comment: @ioch I don't understand exactly what you're asking

Answer (score -1):

If $A$ is a special matrix other than a scalar multiple of the identity matrix and $A$ and $B$ are similar, but $B$ has a basis of eigenvectors such that there are two non-orthogonal eigenvectors $u$ and $v$ for distinct eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$, respectively, then $B$ will not have the special property.

(Note, by the way, a self-adjoint matrix is the same thing as a Hermitian matrix.)